# Elasticsearch how do get Sum in aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on Elasticsearch 1.5.2. I stored these products : "sel 1", "sel 2", "haricot 1" and "haricot 2"

```
  POST /test/prod
{
    "titre": "sel 1",
    "prix en €": 2.49 ,
    "prix en €/kg": 5.20 

}

POST /test/prod
{
    "titre": "sel 2",
    "prix en €": 2 ,
    "prix en €/kg": 4.3 

}

POST /test/prod
{
    "titre": "haricot 1",
    "prix en €": 14 ,
    "prix en €/kg": 0.85 

}

POST /test/prod
{
    "titre": "haricot 2",
    "prix en €": 36 ,
    "prix en €/kg": 4 

}
```

I make one query to get the cheapest "prix en €/kg" of product sel and the cheapest "prix en €/kg" of product haricot.

```
POST test/_search?search_type=count
{
"aggs" : {
    "sel" : {
        "filter" : {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                   "query": "sel",
                   "fields": [
                      "titre"
                   ]
                }
            }
        },
            "aggs" : {
                "minprice": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "prix en €/kg": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "haricots" : {
        "filter" : {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                   "query": "haricot",
                   "fields": [
                      "titre"
                   ]
                }
            }

    },
            "aggs" : {
                "minprice": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "prix en €/kg": {
                                    "order": "asc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works. Now I want to get the sum of "prix en €" of (the cheapest "sel" + the cheapest "haricot"). So how can I do it?

Comment: You cannot have a `query_string` inside an aggregation filter

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: In fact, I can have query_string inside aggregation filter, but I am working on Elasticsearch 1.5.2. so I must add a query object around query_string. I runned it and it works. Thank you.

Comment: I just forget to notice the version of ES ! which is important! Thank you for help, I appreciate it.